# Insert a new field when primary keys from two separate tables match

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have two tables one is called `Players` and the other is `importdata`.  The `importdata` table consists of two fields the player id (PID) and the photo (Photo).

In the `Players` table I created a column for the Photo field to be imported into.  What I would like to do is take the Photo field from the `importdata` table and insert it into the `photo_high` field in the `Players` table where the PID fields match.

I thought something like this would work, but it says that there is an unknown column.

```
INSERT INTO (`photo_high`)
SELECT PID, Photo
FROM importdata
WHERE Players.PID = importdata.PID
```

Can this be achieved with an SQL statement or do I have to write some kind of script?  Any guidance would be great.

## Players

PID
photo_high (empty)

## importdata

PID
Photo (full of content)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `update` rather than `insert`:

```
update Players p join
       ImportData id
       on p.Pid = id.pid
    set photo_high = id.photo;
```

`insert` creates new rows in a table.  `update` changes values in existing fields.